# Sikuli, [error] SyntaxError ( "mismatched input '' expecting EOF", ) in IDE

Tags: ide, eof, sikuli

I have error message and i have no idea why, i don't understand it. Would you help me with that?

```
click("1421761210416.png")
type("word" + Key.ENTER)
click("1421761958712.png")

    if not exists("1421763759437.png"):

        type("1421761996196.png", 'user@user.com')
        type("1421762031575.png", "password")
        click("1421762050819.png")
        find("1421762541898.png")
    else: 
        click("1421763045705.png")


Errors:
[error] script [ test ] stopped with error in line 4 at column 4
[error] SyntaxError ( "mismatched input '' expecting EOF", )
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is not indented properly.

```
click("1421761210416.png")
type("word" + Key.ENTER)
click("1421761958712.png")

if not exists("1421763759437.png"):
    type("1421761996196.png", 'user@user.com')
    type("1421762031575.png", "password")
    click("1421762050819.png")
    find("1421762541898.png")
else: 
    click("1421763045705.png")
```

Your indentation suggested that your if should be part of other loop/if which it wasn't.

Comment: Yes, thank you! That was a problem with indentation (stupid).